# How can I limit the rotation on the Y axis so the player cant spin the camera 360 in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an upcoming project that I have to present on Monday an this is the last bug I have to resolve. It would be nice if someone helped me out and teach me how to apply the axis limiter. Thanks in advance everyone.
The issue is the camera can spin 360 degrees and its the only bug left for the project I'm working on.

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.AI;
 
 public class CharController_Motor : MonoBehaviour {
 
     private float speed = 10.0f;
 
 public float walkSpeed=7.0f;
 public float runSpeed = 12.0f;

 public float sensitivity = 30.0f;
 public float WaterHeight = 15.5f;
 CharacterController character;
 private GameObject cam;

 private NavMeshAgent nav;
 private bool AIActive = true;

 public GameObject cam1;
 public GameObject cam2;//Nightvision
 //private bool NightVision = false;




 float moveFB, moveLR;
 float rotX, rotY;
 

 float gravity = -9.8f;

 public float Stamina = 10f;
 public float MaxStamina = 10f;
 public int DecayRate = 1;
 public float RefillRate=0.25f;

 public GameObject LightBreathing;
 public GameObject HeavyBreathing;
 private bool LightBreath = false;
 private bool HeavyBreath = false;


 public GameObject LowHealthSound;



 public GameObject PlayerDeath;


 public GameObject ChaseMusic;
 void Start(){
     //LockCursor ();
 
     character = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
     SaveScript.PlayerHealth = 30;
 
         
         sensitivity = sensitivity * 1.5f;
         speed = walkSpeed;
         Cursor.visible = false;

         cam = cam1;
         cam2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         LightBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         HeavyBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
         AIActive = true;
         LowHealthSound.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         PlayerDeath.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         ChaseMusic.gameObject.SetActive(false);

 }


 void CheckForWaterHeight(){
     if (transform.position.y < WaterHeight) {
         gravity = 0f;            
     } else {
         gravity = -9.8f;
     }
 }



 void Update(){
     if (LightBreath == false)
     {
         if (Stamina < 3)
         {
             LightBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(true);
             HeavyBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             LightBreath = true;
         }
     }
     if (LightBreath == true)
     {
         if (Stamina > 3)
         {
             LightBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             HeavyBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             LightBreath = false;
         }
     }
     if (HeavyBreath == false)
     {
         if (Stamina == 0)
         {
             LightBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             HeavyBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(true);
             HeavyBreath = true;
         }
     }
     if (HeavyBreath == true)
     {
         if (Stamina > 0)
         {
             LightBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             HeavyBreathing.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             HeavyBreath = false;
         }
     }
     if (Stamina > 0)
     {

         if (Input.GetButton("Run"))
         {
             speed = runSpeed;
             Stamina = Stamina - DecayRate * Time.deltaTime;
             if (Stamina < 0)
             {
                 Stamina = 0;
             }
             
         }
         else
         {
             speed = walkSpeed;
             Stamina = Stamina + RefillRate * Time.deltaTime;
             if (Stamina > MaxStamina)
             {
                 Stamina = MaxStamina;
             }
         }
     }
     if (Stamina == 0)
     {
         speed = walkSpeed;
         StartCoroutine(StaminaRefill());
     }
     if (SaveScript.PlayerHealth < 5)
     {
         LowHealthSound.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     }
     if (SaveScript.PlayerHealth > 4)
     {
         LowHealthSound.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     }
     if(SaveScript.PlayerHealth <= 0)
     {
         PlayerDeath.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     }



     if (AIActive == true)
     {
         nav.enabled = true;
     }
     else 
     {
         nav.enabled = false;
     }
     if (SaveScript.NightVision==false)
     {
         cam = cam1;
         cam2.gameObject.SetActive(false);//Deactivate NightVision
         SaveScript.NightVision = false;
     }
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
         {
         if (SaveScript.NightVision == false)
         {
             cam2.gameObject.SetActive(true);//Activate NightVision
             cam = cam2;
             SaveScript.NightVision = true;
         }
         else
         {
             cam = cam1;
             cam2.gameObject.SetActive(false);//Deactivate NightVision
             SaveScript.NightVision = false;
         }
     }

     moveFB = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * speed;
     moveLR = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;

     rotX = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
     rotY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
     

     //rotX = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Joystick1Button4);
     //rotY = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Joystick1Button5);

     CheckForWaterHeight ();


     Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveFB, gravity, moveLR);



     CameraRotation(cam, rotX, rotY);
     
     movement = transform.rotation * movement;
     character.Move (movement * Time.deltaTime);
 

 }


 void CameraRotation(GameObject cam, float rotX, float rotY){        
     transform.Rotate (0, rotX * Time.deltaTime, 0);
     cam.transform.Rotate (-rotY * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
     
 }

 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Water"))
     {
         AIActive = false;
     }
 }
 private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Water"))
     {
         AIActive = true;
     }
 }
 IEnumerator StaminaRefill()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(MaxStamina);//Wait 10 seconds before setting stamina to max
     if (Stamina == 0)
     {
         Stamina = MaxStamina;
     }
 }
 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED.** If i understand correctly this - `-rotY * Time.deltaTime` makes your camera spin on Y axis. You can limit rotY value between 90 and 180 like this:

```
 void CameraRotation(GameObject cam, float rotX, float rotY){ 
    if(rotY > 180f /*Some value to limit*/)
    {
      rotY = 180f;
    }       
    else if(rotY < 90f /*Some value to limit*/ )
    {
      rotY = 90f;
    }
     transform.Rotate (0, rotX * Time.deltaTime, 0);
     cam.transform.Rotate (-rotY * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
 }
```

And, i think transform.Rotate uses x,y,z values. Why does your `cam.transform.Rotate` rotating with `-rotY` (y) value on it's x axis?

Comment: I dont want it frozen, I want it to stop the rotation at a certain point for looking down and up.

Comment: I tried this now but the camera is spinning continiously on the Y axis, without me moving it.